# Why this If statement with OR operation doesn't work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code to redirect users to the mobile UI. First it will check if it's a mobile second it will check if there is a cookie, and third is to check the URL if NOT contains these words ("DispForm,NewForm,EditForm"). But just doesn't

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("DesktopView=") < 0) {
            if (document.location.href.indexOf('NewForm') === -1 || document.location.href.indexOf('DispForm') === -1 || document.location.href.indexOf('EditForm') === -1) {
                document.location = "/_layouts/Mobile/index.aspx";
            }                                
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking to see if the URL "doesn't contain NewForm" OR "doesn't contain DispForm" etc.

You probably mean `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

it's checking if there **is not** a cookie:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("DesktopView=") < 0) {...}
```

If you want to check if there is a cookie it should be:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("DesktopView=") >= 0) {...}
```

Comment: Yes correct and it works find. The problem is with the there If statement.